# Delete a line using SED from a file and redirect the output to same file

Tags: unix, sed, solaris, ksh

I use sed command to delete first two lines and last  line from a file and i want to redirect the output to the SAME file

EXAMPLE :

```
sed '1,2d' '$d' pra >pra
```

this deletes first two lines & last line  from the file .But when i try to redirect the output to Same file , an Problem Occurs .

when i open and see the the redirected file `pra` nothing is present inside the file .

IS there a better way of doing this ..deleting first two lines and last line from a file and and saving it with the same file Name .

Comment: Use `sed -i '1,2d' ...` instead.

Comment: Numerous questions would tell you that reading and writing to same file would truncate it.

Comment: @DEVNULL i am using Solaris 10 AND Working in kshell its an illegal option there .

Comment: @devnull is there a better way of doing it ,i.e using anyother option

Comment: Chances are that you are using BSD sed.  `sed -i'' '1,2d' pra` might work for you.

Comment: @devnull Am jus curious to know ,why the truncate happens .. ? any constraints set in unix ?

Comment: When you say `command > file` the file is immediately truncated and opened for writing even before the command is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible on Solaris 10, unless you have GNU sed installed as an optional package. Anyway it is safest to use an intermediate file and use the -i option with a backup file.

On Solaris 10 you could do this instead:

```
sed '1,2d; $d' file > file.new && mv file.new file
```

Answer (score 8):

To save output to same file, use --in-place or -i modifier.

E.g.

```
sed -i options_you_want name_of_file_to_change
```

It's much neater than redirecting to temp files, and then back to original file.

As pointed out below, --in-place may not be available on Solaris...

Comment: do not believe the in-place option is available by default on Solaris